# Issue with incorporating BERT in RASA Pipeline

Tags: chatbot, rasa-nlu, rasa, huggingface-transformers

BERT provides an option to include pre-trained language models from Hugging Face in pipline. [As per the doc:](https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/nlu/components/#hftransformersnlp)

```
  - name: HFTransformersNLP
    # Name of the language model to use
    model_name: "bert"
    # Pre-Trained weights to be loaded
    model_weights: "bert-base-uncased"

    # An optional path to a specific directory to download and cache the pre-trained model weights.
    # The `default` cache_dir is the same as https://huggingface.co/transformers/serialization.html#cache-directory .
    cache_dir: null
```

Following this I configured my pipeline as:

```
- name: "HFTransformersNLP"
      # Name of the language model to use
      model_name: "bert"
      # Pre-Trained weights to be loaded
      model_weights: "bert-base-uncased"
      cache_dir: "C:/Project ABC/cache/"
```

But the problem is that on running the training steps, the model keeps failing with:

> OSError: Model name 'bert-base-uncased' was not found in tokenizers
>   model name list (bert-base-uncased, bert-large-uncased,
>   bert-base-cased, bert-large-cased, bert-base-multilingual-uncased,
>   bert-base-multilingual-cased, bert-base-chinese,
>   bert-base-german-cased, bert-large-uncased-whole-word-masking,
>   bert-large-cased-whole-word-masking,
>   bert-large-uncased-whole-word-masking-finetuned-squad,
>   bert-large-cased-whole-word-masking-finetuned-squad,
>   bert-base-cased-finetuned-mrpc, bert-base-german-dbmdz-cased,
>   bert-base-german-dbmdz-uncased, bert-base-finnish-cased-v1,
>   bert-base-finnish-uncased-v1, bert-base-dutch-cased). We assumed
>   'bert-base-uncased' was a path, a model identifier, or url to a
>   directory containing vocabulary files named ['vocab.txt'] but couldn't
>   find such vocabulary files at this path or url.

I did some research and it looks like that there might be issue in downloading the files from internet,  so I manually downloaded the files config.json, pytorch_model.bin and placed it in C:/Project ABC/cache/ still I am getting the same error message. Any idea how to resolve this, not giving cache directory is failing too with the same error.

Comment: Can you share the link to the documentation and update the question accordingly?

Comment: updated in the question too, the reference to the doc is: https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/nlu/components/#hftransformersnlp

Comment: I have downloaded and placed the vocab.txt file in the same cache folder. Still getting the same error.